# need help in converting column values to separate columns

Tags: mysql, powerbi

I have a sample table as below in mysql
[SAMPLE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBVNZ.png)

and I am trying to create a new table as below for each req id in mysql
[DESIRED TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFMNE.png)

Please provide your suggestions on how to achieve either in MySQL or Power BI

I am unable to achieve the desired output table

Comment: [MySQL - Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns).